# How to distinguish admin and customer role when create user with createUserWithEmailAndPassword firebase auth in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have two reactjs websites, one for client user and one for admin. I have graphql api for data access. Currently, admin is using JWT and we will change to firebase authentication.

I already implement both login and registration using firebase package.

here is the create user function. So it worked and can login successfully. But my question is that how can I distinguish admin user and customer user. I saw that setCustomUserClaims is only for firebase-admin. May I know how to set the role in firebase and what is the correct way to set?

```
function register(name, email, password) {
return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((res) => {
  const auth = getAuth();
  
  updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
    displayName: name
  }).then(() => {
    // Profile updated!
    // ...
  }).catch((error) => {
    // An error occurred
    // ...
    console.log(error.message);
  });
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) are definitely the easiest way to add roles in Firebase Auth but you'll need to use [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) in a [Cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions) or any secure server environment.

> I saw that `setCustomUserClaims` is only for `firebase-admin`

`setCustomUserClaims()` is used to *set* the custom claims but you can always read them using [`getIdTokenResult()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#getidtokenresult) function in client SDK.

```
const { claims } = await getIdTokenResult(auth.currentUser)
```

So if your GraphQL API runs on your own server you can install Firebase Admin there and add custom claims to Firebase auth users.

Alternatively, you can store user role in a database like [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore) or your own database and read user's role from there. One catch of store roles in a database is that you cannot access them from security rules of other services like Firebase storage if required but custom claims can be.

Comment: Yes, defiantly. I only concerned is that using firebae-admin at client. Anyway, now after authenticated from client, then call the api for to verify token and set the claim at api and store the user info with role in db. Thanks for answer.